# using android lib project in two different build versions project

Tags: android, android-library, android-build

I have  android project that Its is now a android library project.
I have set up two projects(A and B)  that use the library project.
So for example when I start project A it uses all of the activities from the lib project.
The question is how to now make the library project start a activity from the project A?
Lats say that LibActivity is a activity defined in the libProject so for example I have:

```
**LibActivity1** starts **LibActivity2**
**LibActivity2** starts **LibActivty3** 
and now I need LibActivity3 to start **projectA_Activity** or **projectBActivity** 
depending on the build
```

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps explain what your trying to achieve by calling an activity from your lib, i would have thought that your activities in the lib would come to a natural end, and not be dependant on another project. As such you could call the lib activity with a startActivityForResult() call, then finish() in the lib to return to the main activity.

Answer (score 0):

I would call the library activity with a startActivityForResult() call and then finish() the library activity, returning to your Project activity. You can then test the result to determine which project activity to move on to next.

Comment: thanks for the response but i solved using reflection: Class activity=HotelDistrictListActivity.class.getClassLoader().loadClass(      "com.myactivity.CreditCartActivity"); startActivity(this,activity)